# mouse events with buttons: mouseover, onclick, static

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

I'd like a button to have 3 different states (3 different images of the same button)
-static
-hover
-click
-release (back to static)

I've found plenty of examples of mouseover chaning the image, but nothing with the click option.

Thanks :)

Comment: `onclick` is not a `mouse-` event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

High-level answer: use the CSS1 [`:active` pseudo-class](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-active).

```
#myButton {
    /* static state */
}

#myButton:hover {
    /* hover state */
}

#myButton:active {
    /* state while clicked but not released */
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the CSS tag ;)

Comment: Ohhh, nice! Thank you. Didn't know css could do that :)

Answer (score 0):

The events you want are `mouseover`, `mouseout`, `mousedown`, and `mouseup`

From there you can easily move the background:

```
document.getElementById('my_element').style.backgroundPosition='100px 100px'
```